# Rules governing overline usage in Roman numerals

Tags: number-systems

In the modern usage of Roman numerals, how would a number such as 1,001,000 be converted to Roman numerals? Would it be $\overline{\mathrm M}$${\mathrm M}$ or $\overline{\mathrm {MI}}$?

Is there a set of rules governing when to use ${\mathrm M}$ and when to use $\overline{\mathrm I}$? These are the only two symbols in Roman numerals with the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://home.hiwaay.net/%7Elkseitz/math/roman/numerals.shtml) claims that $\overline{\mathrm I}$ was not used because of M. But the historical examples given by [this page](http://www.web40571.clarahost.co.uk/roman/howtheywork.htm#larger) suggests that something like $\overline{\mathrm{MI}}$ might have been a fine way to write it. Of note is that [this Dr. Math page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180205154231/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57569.html) suggests the vertical bar/parentheses method may have preceded M and the overline, but I don't know if $\left||\mathrm I|\mathrm I\right|$ was ever an option.